# Deixar clique no A em toda a LI

Tags: css

Tenho o HTML:

```
<li class="duoBtsAnalise"><a href="#">Análises de Risco</a></li>
```

Quero que o clique do `a` esteja ativo em toda a `li`.

Meu CSS:

```
  .duoBtsAnalise {
    background-image: url("../imagens/duoAnalise.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 183px;
    height: 182px;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 135px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;

}
```

Estou pedindo isso, pois a `li` é um quadrado grande e o `a` é apenas o texto.

Comment: O melhor no meu ver, seria formatar o A como block de modo a ficar ocupando o quadrado, em vez de estilizar só a li.

Comment: @Bacco era isso mesmo cara, não sei como não pensei nisso antes, valeu

Comment: @Bacco resposta formal ;)

Comment: @Felipe se conseguir resolver desta forma e achar que o resultado ficou bom, considere postar como resposta para deixar completo o post.

Comment: (só não esqueça de passar o padding pra dentro do A)

Answer (score 4):

Visto que o seu `<li>` possui largura e altura definidas, bastaria definir o `<a>` com `display: block` ocupando 100% de largura e altura:

```css
li {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px
}

a {
    background: skyblue;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

/* Não importante */
a {line-height:35px;text-align:center;color:#fff;text-decoration:none}
```

```html
<li>
    <a href='#'>Análise de riscos</a>
</li>
```

Defini a cor de *background* no `<a>` para mostrar que ele está ocupando 100% do `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

tente isso:

```
.duoBtsAnalise a {
  background-image: url("../imagens/duoAnalise.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 183px;
  height: 182px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 135px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
 }
```